# If there is a colon (:) in the directory name, how could I add it to $PATH?

Tags: macos, path, bash

I am using `mac os x`, and I have some trouble setting the `$PATH` env. If the directory name is `/path/to/add/a:b/bin`, how can I add this directory to `$PATH` which is separated by `:`?

Comment: From the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html): "Since <colon> is a separator in this context, directory names that might be used in PATH should not include a <colon> character."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't.  The obvious way to escape a `:` character in `$PATH` would be to use a backslash, but a quick experiment with Bash on Linux indicates that it doesn't work. OSX might behave differently, but I suspect you'd have the same problem.

Your best bet is to rename the directory. If it really needs to have that name, you can create a symbolic link and add that to your `$PATH`:

```
 $ cd /path/to/add
 $ ln -s a:b a_b
 $ PATH="$PATH:/path/to/add/a_b/bin"
```